# How to manage UISplitView application for iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

[image]

I am creating this application by windowBased application in `UISplitView` on leftside i have list name of 10 xib , if i select any cell for open view on detailview so how to open it how open diffrent view on detailview i try this last two day i not get any solution please help me how show diffrent view on detailview right side please help me on this.

in this image i have left side all view name 7 view name if click any view so it should open on rightside view so how to do please explain me and if i click any other view then toolbar should be hide according to different view.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to visit this tutorial :

http://www.scienceathand.com/idevblogaday/adventures-in-uisplitviewcontroller-2/

Source code:

https://github.com/toddwbates/MultipleMasterDetailViews

**Edit 1:**

For implementing it in below iOS 5.0 try this Apple sample code.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775

Comment: i want to do by window based application

Comment: You can have Empty Application while creating new project and then manually add classes to it..

Comment: in this application only appdelegate is retain how it done when we create any new project if we write name of project then it show projctappdelegate in this application project name is diffrent and adddeleget name separate from application name how to to